# Add hibernate from Netbeans JPA for existing Jersey project

Tags: hibernate, jpa, gradle, jersey, netbeans-8

I've created an REST application on Netbeans 8.2 Gradle project using this tutorial and it worked:
https://dragonflytechblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/restful-services-using-jersey-jetty-and-gradle/

I also has an existing PostgreSQL database.

How to create Data Source to connect to that database then apply Hibernate framework using Netbeans JPA to this project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to add hibernate core and entity manager to your Gradle build, you can get them from Hibernate's official website : http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ 
 in addition you have to add the Hibernate properties where you should write the database connection info (url , username ,pwd ..etc) , generally added to (other sources) in NetBeans.
hope this helps.